# 0 results in MS Access totals query (w. COUNT) after applying criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

A query I am working on is showing a rather interesting behaviour that I couldn't debug so far. 
This is the query before it gets buggy:

QryCount

```
SELECT EmpId, [Open/Close], Count([Open/Close]) AS Occurences, Attribute1, Market, Tier, Attribute2, MtSWeek
FROM qrySource
WHERE (Venue="NewYork") AND (Type="TypeA")
GROUP BY EmpId, [Open/Close], Attribute1, Market, Tier, Attribute2, MtSWeek;
```

The query gives precisely the results that I would expect it to:

```
#01542 | Open   | 5 | Call | English | Tier1 | Complain | 01/01/2017
#01542 | Closed | 2 | Call | English | Tier2 | ProdInfo | 01/01/2017
#01542 | Open   | 7 | Mail | English | Tier1 | ProdInfo | 08/01/2017
etc...
```

But as a matter of fact in doing so it provides more records than needed at a subsequent step thereby creating cartesians.

qrySource.[Open/Close] is a string type field with possible attributes (you guessed) "open", "Closed" and null and it is actually provided by a mapping table at the creation stage of qrySource (not sure, but maybe this helps).

Now, the error comes in when I try to limit qryCount only to records where Open/Close = "Open".
I tried both using `WHERE` and `HAVING` to no avail. The query would result in 0 records, which is not what I would like to see.
I thought that maybe it is because "open" is a reserved term, but even by changing it to "D_open" in the source table didn't fix the issue.
Also tried to filter for the desired records in a subsequent query

```
SELECT *
FROM QryCount
WHERE [Open/Close] ="D_Open"
```

But nothing, still 0 records found.

I am suspicious it might be somehow related to some inherent proprieties of the COUNT function but not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reserved words do not affect data values. It is only an issue with identifiers such as table and column names. Can you set up a reproducible example so we can recreate your issue such as original table records and the query, *qrySource*?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using a base table named "qrySource". I agree with @Parfait that you will need to create a [mcve] that can illustrate the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your select statement is correct? Shouldn't `WHERE [Open/Close] ="D_Open"` read `WHERE [Open/Close] ="Open"`?

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who participated, thank you and apologies for providing you with insufficient/confusing information. I recon the question could have been drafted better.

Anyhow, I found that the problem was apparently caused by the "/" in the Open/Closed field name. As soon as I removed it from the field name in the original mapping table the query performed as expected.